# Concavity of quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratic-forms

I know that the quadratic form $x'Ax$ is a concave in vector $x$ if matrix $A$ is negative semi definite. What happens if $A$ depends on $x$ (so that I have $x'A(x)x$), but I still know that $A(x)$ is NSD? Does it still hold?
Maybe that's not even a quad.form in that case$\dots$ anyways how do I check concavity in that case?

More generally if let $m$ be a vector valued function of vector $x$, so $m=m(x)$, and let $A$ be a NSD matrix dependent on $x$, so $A=A(x)$. What is then the derivative of $m'Am$ w.r.t. $x$?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: No, concavity does not hold in general. Working in $\mathbb R^2$, let $A(x)=-I$ if $x_1=0$ and $A(x)=-100I$ otherwise. Then $f(x)=x^TA(x)x$ is not concave because $\frac12f([-1,1]^T)+\frac12f([1,1]^T) = -2 > -100 = f(\frac12[-1,1]^T+\frac12[1,1]^T)$.

Comment: Oops, that should be $x_1\ne0$ above.

Answer (score 1):

Rahul is right, but his function $A$ is not differentiable. Unfortunately, when $A$ is differentiable, then the second derivative is complicated. Let $A=[a_{i,j}]$ and if $U$ is a matrix, then $[U]_i$ denotes its $i^{th}$ column.
One has

$\dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_kx_l}:x\rightarrow 2a_{k,l}+x^T\dfrac{\partial^2A}{\partial x_kx_l}x+2x^T([\dfrac{\partial A}{\partial x_k}]_l+[\dfrac{\partial A}{\partial x_l}]_k)$.

Finally, is the following symmetric matrix: $Hess(f)=[\dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_kx_l}]_{kl}$ non-positive ?